# "Commit" option with the green check mark icon not appearing in Subversion tab IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, svn, commit

I've ran into a problem where in IntelliJ Settings->Appearance & Behavior->Menus and Toolbars->VCS Local Changes Toolbar I see the "Commit" option with the green check mark icon. However, the green check mark is not showing up in the 9.Subversion tab at the bottom of the IDE window. Does somebody by chance know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Please check that there is no separate "Commit" tool window.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite dumm - I forgot I had already committed the day before.